# Can you compile for Windows using WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, godot, scons

Edit: I have been informed that I have a Godot-specific error. I'm going to leave the question up so people can look at my idiocy and also to help the one poor soul in the future who sees this. I still don't know why though, I'll be going to the Godot Game Engine Discord, and will update here if I figure a solution out.

Yes that also *was* me writing above, not someone trying to be rude.

**vvv Original Content vvv**

I'm trying to build the Godot Game Engine from source to edit with Windows 10 with extra modules, and I want to use Windows Subsystem for Linux in order to do that. When I installed SCons and set everything up, I was only able to choose the platform `linuxbsd`. Is there a way to compile it for Windows using WSL?

I've tried going to Google and looking at the SCons website but I can only seem to find out an explanation on how to install SCons which I already did with `sudo apt install scons`.

Running the command `scons platform=windows profile=custom.py` where custom.py is an autogenerated file I got from the Godot docs.

```
Invalid target platform "windows".
The following platforms were detected:

        linuxbsd

Please run SCons again and select a valid platform: platform=<string>
```

Comment: Please include what your command line was when you tried to run SCons which yielded the error message above. (Note that error message is from the Godot specific SCons build logic, and not from SCons itself)

Comment: WSL is still Linux, so you'd need cross compiling. You can also install SCons in Windows instead of in WSL. That would probably work better in this case.

Comment: In general, you can build Windows binaries using mingw; there are mingw packages for at least some common Linux distributions. Ubuntu, which is one of the best supported WSL choices, is one of them.  That said, scons doesn't know anything specific about mingw on Linux so that would take some work (it does know about mingw on win32); but really, this comes down to what configurations Godot supports.  A Godot channel might be the best place to get help (good that you tagged this question with godot).